# How can MVVM Light be used in a WPF User Control Library project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mvvm-light

Specifically, I would like to know how the view model is to be bound to a user control.  The examples I have been able to find so far are all WPF Application or WPF Browser Application projects.  Even the templates in tool kit are for WPF Application or WPF Browser Application projects.  I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the ff. in the comments of MVVM Light's site: http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2010/03/whats-new-in-mvvm-light-v3/.  Basically, in lieu of App.xaml, the view model locator is declared as a resource in the user control.  The framework's creator himself has spoken so I suppose this must be the best approach :D

Comment: Really wish you had shared a link directly to the page the comment is/was on.

Alternately, the site curators may have pruned the comment referred to as it does not appear at the url above :(