# MVVM-Light and WPF User control library

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, mvvm-light

I will have to create a WPF user control in a stand alone user control library.
I want to use MVVM-light.
Question, the SimpleIOC is normally setup in the Main application and added as a resource to the Main application through app.xaml.

How do I best solve it such that the referenced user control library get access to the SimpleIOC container?
Where do I best register the User control's ViewModel(s)?

I found the following thread that seems to be the same question, but there is no longer any information about the solution in the link provided in the answer post.
[How can MVVM Light be used in a WPF User Control Library project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733795/how-can-mvvm-light-be-used-in-a-wpf-user-control-library-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the views in the stand-alone class library have a dependency upon a view model locator which in turn has dependencies upon the view model classes, you could define the `ViewModelLocator` class as a singleton in the view model project and reference this project from both the User Control library and the WPF application itself:

[image]

**ViewModels/ViewModelLocator.cs:**

```
public sealed class ViewModelLocator
{
    private static readonly ViewModelLocator _instance = new ViewModelLocator();

    private ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public static ViewModelLocator Instance => _instance;

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Views/UserControl1.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ViewModels;assembly=ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={x:Static viewModels:ViewModelLocator.Instance}}">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**WpfApp4/MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Views;assembly=Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <views:UserControl1 />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks this is more or less what I look for.
In my case the MainViewModel will be located in the WpfApp4 and the UserControl will have its UserControlViewModel in the Views project.

Currently the ViewModelLocator is in the WpfApp4 project as well, but I see no reason why I could not move it to a separate project. The concept explained here is certainly what I look for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear which part of this you're having problems with. The view models in your library can be registered the same way as any other view model:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<YourClassLibrary.YourClassLibViewModel>();
... etc ...
```

If your class library has objects that need to be included in the main application resource dictionary (i.e. DataTemplates etc) then put them in a ResourceDictionary just as you normally would do in App.xaml....

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourClassLibrary">

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YourClassLibViewModel}">
        <local:YourClassLibUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

...and then add this to your main application's ResourceDictionary's `MergedDictionaries` list:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YourClasssLibrary;component/YourResourceDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:YourMainApp.ViewModel" />

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry if I am not clear (have not too much experience with WPF). So please be patient. If I create a MVVM Light Application I have a ViewModelLocator in the MainApplication that holds a SimpleIOC.

In my case I also  have a user control in a separate user control library project in the same solution. The user control I will place in the main application later. But I need somehow to make that user control aware of the SimpleIOC or use its own SimpleIOC Locator, register its VMs to it and in the View(s) bind to the VM instance in the Locator.

How to do it in a User control library?

Comment: I'd just create an instance of your control library (e.g. `MyClassModule`) and give it a function that accepts something of type `ISimpleIoc` and calls `ISimpleIoc.Register()` for each of your view models. Then back in your view locator have it call that function, passing in a reference to itself i.e. `new MyClassModule().RegisterViewModels(this)`.

Comment: I have tried that, but my problem then that the VMs are not available in the XAML editor during design time so I cannot choose to bind to a VM property.

Comment: What seems to work is to create a new ViewModelLocator in the User control library in a local ResourceDictionary, and work with its Ioc container inside the user control. But it means the MainApplication and the User control do not share the same Ioc container.

Comment: I'm not following....what do you mean they're "not available in the XAML editor"? So long as you declare the namespace correctly it'll work fine. The only real difference is that the namespace declaration also has to specify the assembly e.g. `xmlns:libvms="clr-namespace:YourProject.ViewModels;assembly=YourProject"`. Then you just specify them in your XAML as `libvms:YourViewModel`.

Comment: I think you're going to have to post the exact code you're using and point to which bits aren't working the way you want them to. This is all very straightforward, it's just not clear exactly which part is causing you problems.

Comment: I think I am missing the part with assembly in the XAML namespace.
I will investigate before posting all code. Thanks a lot for the help so far.